# jquery validationg .jpg extension pass for any file extension

Tags: jquery

I am validating a picture uploaded is jpg or not as below code

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" />

var fileName = $('#pic').val();
alert(fileName);  //give result c:\fakepath\123.xls
if (fileName != '') {
    alert("Entered if");
    var ext = $('#pic').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    if (ext != 'jpg') {
        error = 1;
        alert(error);
    }
}
```

If i select any file this validation is passing. So I put two alerts. Now the first alert will show the file path selected. but any how it is not getting inside the if condition so second alert is not doing so no check for the extension is happening. The if condition is true because fileName show the file path so it is not equal to ''

Comment: Can you provide plnkr ??

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi didn't get u sorry

Comment: provide your code here jsfiddle.net and provide the link

Comment: What is the value of `filename` your testing. What is the value of `ext`? Add some `console.log()` statements so you can check the results.

Comment: @Anikislamabhi here is the fiddle link [link]http://jsfiddle.net/hishamkmr/amwc3mtg/

Comment: @StephenMuecke the value of filename will be the path `C;\123.xls` iam not able to check the value of ext because it is not entering the if condition

Comment: If this if the value of a `<input type="file">` then it wont include the path (that is never present in the value - only the file name). You code works fine when I test it with (say) `MyDocument.xls`

Comment: @StephenMuecke see my modified question..the value is path..don't know why ..also its not entering if

Comment: @Sachu, See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amwc3mtg/2/) - works fine and alerts `1` if I select any file that is not `.jpg`

Answer (score 2):

I have used this... works for me

HTML...

```
Picture <input type="file" id="pic" onchange="pic_val()" >
```

JS..

```
function pic_val()
{   
    var fileName = $('#pic').val();
    alert(fileName);
    if (fileName != '') {
        alert("Entered if");
        var ext = $('#pic').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if (ext != 'jpg')
        {
         error = 1;
        alert(error);
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Valid FIle");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
$(function () {

    $("#click").on("click", function () {
        var fileName=   $('#image').val();     
        alert(fileName);
        if (fileName != '') {
            alert("Entered if");
            var ext = fileName.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            if (ext != 'jpg') {
                error = 1;
                alert(error);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cncq05ne/)

Comment: i didn't got your fiddle link..ok if it is the probelm with split() line why it is not alerting the string before that.